# CSS in Shiny: coloring dynamic tabs

Tags: css, r, shiny

Learning CSS, is it possible to assign colors to tabs depending on their title?

Example: creating tabs from vector element names and assigning the element value as color.

```
vec = c("Tab_1" = "#4185FB", "Tab_2" = "#FFC60A", "Tab_3" = "#EB002A")

vec
    Tab_1     Tab_2     Tab_3 
"#4185FB" "#FFC60A" "#EB002A"
```

Shiny app:

```
library(shiny)

vec = c("Tab_1" = "#4185FB", "Tab_2" = "#FFC60A", "Tab_3" = "#EB002A")

ui <- fluidPage(
  do.call(tabsetPanel,
          c(lapply(names(vec),
                   function(x){
                    tab_color = unname(vec[names(vec) == x])
                    
                    tabPanel(tags$head(tags$style(HTML(glue("'
                        .nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover{{
                            color: {tab_color};
                        }}'")))),
                             title = x
                    )
                   }
            ))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This way the colors remain the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
library(shiny)

vec = c("Tab_1" = "#4185FB", "Tab_2" = "#FFC60A", "Tab_3" = "#EB002A")

CSS <- paste0(mapply(
  function(x,y){
    sprintf("
.nav-tabs>li.active>a[data-value='%s'], 
.nav-tabs>li.active>a[data-value='%s']:focus, 
.nav-tabs>li.active>a[data-value='%s']:hover {
  color: %s;
}", x, x, x, y)
  },
  names(vec), vec
), collapse = "\n")

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(CSS))),
  do.call(tabsetPanel,
          c(lapply(names(vec),
                   function(x){
                     tabPanel(
                       title = x
                     )
                   }
          ))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect !

Comment: Just for me to understand a bit further, sometimes I have html elements like `<li class="active"> == $0` for which I would like to change some parameters. Since they don't have a `data-value` attribute, is it possible to change their color based on the children `data-value` for instance?